# input cannot be reset to the default using angular.copy

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am displaying user first name in `div` and have an edit button. Once I click edit, a textbox appears so I can edit the name.

When I click on edit, the textbox takes the same text displayed on the `div` and if I cancel the edit, I want the changes back to the default value which is the `div`... Here is my code:

View:

```
<td>
<div ng-show="!nameElements" class="item_list">{{u.fName}}</div>
<div ng-show="nameElements">
    <input type="text" id="ufn" ng-model="userfName">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateUserName()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.defaultfName = angular.copy(response.data[0].fName);
.
.
.
$scope.toggle = function (elem) {
    $scope.userfName = $scope.defaultfName;//reset input

    $scope.nameElements = !$scope.nameElements;//for the ng-view
};
```

My problem is, when I change the text and click on `cancel` to hide the input as well as reset the text, the text doesn't reset! Which means the same changes remains when I click on edit again.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Angular.copy works fine but for `$scope.defaultfName`.
remove `Angular.copy` from that line and put it for `$scope.userfName`.

```
$scope.defaultfName = angular.copy(response.data[0].fName); //Copy is optional
.
.
.
$scope.toggle = function (elem) {
    $scope.userfName = angular.copy($scope.defaultfName); //no more reference passing!

    $scope.nameElements = !$scope.nameElements;
};
```

And for preventing extra problems from multiple hitting or ... i suggest you to put the code in `$scope.applyAsync`, like this:

```
$scope.toggle = function (elem) {
    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
       //rest of codes ...
    });
};
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work for me, when I click the icon "cancel" that hides the input, it suppose to reset the input, but when I click on edit to show the input again, I see the last edited text still remain

Comment: I have a question, in my view, I have used `ng-repeat=u in users` and I set the `ng-model` in a textbox as `ng-model=u.fName` where `fName` is database field. My question is, how I can represent the `ng-model=u.fName` in the angular controller??